Sonata Admin: Embed Admin in Non-Owning side of Uni-Directional 1-1 relationship
I have two entities with a 1-1 relationship: Activity and ActionConfig.
ActionConfig is the owning side of the relationship. It is a uni-directional, so Activity does not have a property pointing to its ActionConfig.
In Sonata Admin, I have an ActivityAdmin for the Activity entity.
I'd like to embed the admin for the related ActionConfig entity in a tab of this admin, without changing the nature of the relationship.
Normally you'd accomplish that with something like this in your form:
$form->tab('Action config');
$form->add('action_config', AdminType::class);
$form->end();

However, since there's no Activity#$action_config property, that doesn't work.
How can I add the admin

What I've tried so far
I've tried to add an unmapped field with the idea that I'd save/update it in the admin's persist/update hooks. However this configuration:
        $formMapper->tab('Action Config')
            ->add(
                'action_config',
                AdminType::class,
                [
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'label' => 'Action Configuration',
                    'required' => false,
                    'class' => ActionConfig::class,
                    'sonata_field_description' => $this->adminPool->getAdminByClass(ActivityActionPlanConfig::class),
                ],
            )
            ->end();

results in the error

The current field `action_config` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target model: ``.

The ActionConfig class does indeed have a valid admin (I've verified it works standalone, outside of an embedded context).
